# use of "db" in intel x86 architecture and DOSBOX

Tags: assembly, x86, dosbox

I am a bit new to x86 architecture and also to assembly. I have this piece code that I cannot understand.

```
data1 SEGMENT
    dat1 db 'ABCDEFGH'
data1 ENDS
```

which is in the beginning of the code. Later we are using this data1 in the code:

```
mov ax, data1 
mov ds, ax
```

I am using DOSBOX as an emulator and the turbo debugger and in there it shows up as :

```
mov ax, 0B14 
mov ds, ax
```

Any idea why? I also do not understand the use of db in general. Sometimes it is used to display a message, sometimes similar to my example.

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: Is this a typo? `mov ax, donnee1` Did you mean `mov ax,data1`?

Comment: @user3144770 yes it was thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The `db` statement is used to define bytes. This is not actually an instruction, rather the assembly user putting custom data somewhere. This data is at a specific location in memory, so the disassembled data shows an address, instead of the label, which is used in the code. The label is just a placeholder for the address, which is assigned by the assembler.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that *data1* is in the beginning of the code is not too important. The assembler/linker will give it a suitable location in the EXE. So it's perfectly possible to see `mov ax, 0B14` in the debugger. 0B14h is the address where this data segment was placed in the EXE.

There's not much difference between your example and the use of `db` to display a message. At most in the latter case a terminating byte would have been added.

```
dat1 db 'ABCDEFGH'

dat1 db 'ABCDEFGH',0

dat1 db 'ABCDEFGH','$'
```

Comment: ok thank you very much but now I have one more question:) then when I go in ds to 0B14 I should be able to see 'ABCDEFGH', probably in ascii but when I do, I see some random numbers. By the way, we say, assume ds: data1 so it should be in ds

Comment: If the value 0B14h is the actually encoded value in the EXE then it will get changed by the relocation process of the program loader. Thus you have to know where things are when you use a debugger. Can't help you there.

Comment: @thebok and user-numberguy: 0B14 is the *segment*, not the address within the segment.  Once your code does `mov ds, ax`, the memory at `ds:[dat1]` should hold your ASCII string.  Note that `data1` is a segment label, `dat1` is a regular label. IDK if DOS programs get any runtime relocation. The 16bit segmented memory model is not a very useful thing to learn, esp. if you're just trying to learn assembly. The useful thing to do with asm these days is mostly writing optimized inner loops (e.g. for stuff like video codecs), that run in 64bit mode with paged memory. See http://agner.org/optimize/